# Why can't I open a shared memory object although O_CREAT is set?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have a small C program that opens/creates a `shm` area like this:

```
s = shm_open("/run/shm/procman_power", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if(s >= 0) printf("s = %d\n",s);
else perror("shm_open");
```

But when I execute it, this is what I get:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        73G   23G   47G  33% /
udev            490M  4.0K  490M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  784K  198M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M  360K  497M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   72K  100M   1% /run/user

$ gcc shmtest.c -o shmtest -lrt 
$ ./shmtest 
shm_open: No such file or directory
```

Why it is not creating it? I did get it to work a few days ago and now it's somehow broken...

Comment: You're compiling a program and naming the result of the compilation `shmtest`, but you're running `./shmtestshm_open:`... Is that a shell script, or a different program, or something else entirely? Alternatively, maybe your copy-pasta of your terminal session failed  somehow.

Comment: True! Was just a typo, edited. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared memory objects are not ordinary file system paths, they are just names within an abstract namespace.  According to the [`shm_open(3)` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open):

> For portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name of the form `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of up to `NAME_MAX` (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.

So I would suggest using an object name such as `"/procman_power"` instead of what you're using.

Also note that `shm_open` returns a non-negative integer on success, so that `0` would be a valid success code, not a failure code.  You should be checking `if (s >= 0)` to test if it succeeded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it. The problem was that I had it working previously, setting the name as you stated. After that, I changed the name thinking that it should point to a "path" (though I knew it is not an actual file) and it continued to work (strange isn't it?). After a reboot, I ran the program again and I suddenly realized the `shm_open` was not working. The `if (s >= 0)` was just a typo, thanks for pointing that out too!